# Approximate solve?

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I'm trying to solve the probability that a cumulative discrete distribution (specifically, the negative hypergeometric distribution) equals 0.5 for a particular parameter $\in \mathbb{N}$. Since it's discrete, there is no exact solution, but I was wondering if *Mathematica* had a way to find the nearest solution. At this point I'm reduced to plugging in and guessing, and `NSolve` is not working (probably because its not just checking the naturals).

So I need a approximate solution $\in \mathbb{N}$ that may not be very close.

---

Edit:

Here's the code:

```
Solve[.5 ==
Sum[
    (Binomial[k + 1 - 1, k]*Binomial[540000 - 1 - k, 539000 - k])
    / 
    (Binomial[540000, 539000]
    ),
    {k, 1, n}
   ],
    n, Integers]
```

The (approximate) solution is 375.

Comment: `FindMinimum` of the distribution minus 0.5 could work.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack-Exchange! In general people get much better answers when they copy and paste (as text) the actual Mathematica they've tried. A non-obvious advantage of doing so: not everyone on MSE is a native english speaker, but everyone here speaks Mathematica, so you'll reach a much wider audience.  It takes a little longer but it ends up making both the question and subsequent answers much more valuable.

Comment: `InverseCDF[]` or `Quantile[]` are usable if your distribution is expressible in terms of built-ins.

Comment: For some reason the negative hypergeometric isn't built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [noted in the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BetaBinomialDistribution.html#303742757), the negative hypergeometric is expressible in terms of `BetaBinomialDistribution[]`:

```
NegativeHypergeometricDistribution[r_, nsucc_, ntot_] :=
BetaBinomialDistribution[r, ntot - nsucc - r + 1, nsucc]
```

Check:

```
FullSimplify[(Binomial[k + 1 - 1, k] Binomial[540000 - 1 - k, 539000 - k])/
             (Binomial[540000, 539000]) == 
             PDF[NegativeHypergeometricDistribution[1, 539000, 540000], k], 
             0 <= k <= 539000]
   True
```

Thus, your problem is solved by either of

```
Quantile[NegativeHypergeometricDistribution[1, 539000, 540000], 1/2]
   373
```

or

```
InverseCDF[NegativeHypergeometricDistribution[1, 539000, 540000], 1/2]
   373
```